# C# REST Webclient input type

Tags: c#, php, web-services, rest

i've wrote a small application to test a connection to a webservice i wrote.
My problem is, that i don't know how top change the name of an input type.

My Webservice looks something like that

```
    if ($_FILES["datei"]["error"] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) 
    {
           $tmp_name = $_FILES["datei"]["tmp_name"];
           $name = $_FILES["datei"]["name"];
           move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $this->uploads_dir."$name");
           return $this->uploads_dir.''.$name;
    }
```

I can call it from the webbrowser and everything works fine.

```
<form action="index.php?action=upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<input type="file" name="datei"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Hochladen"> 
</form>
```

But if i try it from my c# code it gets difficult

```
    public static void UploadFilesToRemoteUrl(string url, string datei)
    {
        System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = false;
        WebClient wc = new WebClient();
        byte[] arr = wc.UploadFile(url,"post",datei);

        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding enc = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
        string sr = enc.GetString(arr);
        MessageBox.Show(sr);
    }
```

The code above doesn't work directly.
i figured out that when i change `<input type="file" name="datei">` to <`input type="file" name="file">` it will work.

Here my question can i solve this problem in C# so that i don't have to change the PHP code ?

I think this is a very easy question but i am not so familiar with webdevelopment
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use fiddler (http://fiddler2.com/) to view what are you sending exactly over the wire. You should compare the messages sent by the browser (which works fine) and the message sent by your test app in C#.

Once you know which filed of the HTTP message is wrong, you can try to correct it in the wc object.